# bash logger: Cannot find a way to add MaxBackupIndex to this logger implementation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

I have been trying to modify this logger [implementation](https://code.google.com/p/logger/source/browse/trunk/logger.core) but I cannot manage to make it work. Here's a sample:

```
#!/bin/bash

TRUE=1
FALSE=0

############### Added for testing
logger_LOG_ENABLED=$TRUE

logger_rootLogger=$TRACE,f,s
logger_appender_f=file
logger_appender_f_dir=$(pwd)
logger_appender_f_file=test.log
logger_appender_f_roll_format=%Y%m
logger_appender_f_roll=$TRUE
logger_appender_f_maxBackupIndex=10

####################################

logger_abs(){
    if [ "${1:0:1}" == "." ]; then
        builtin echo ${rootDir}/${1}
    else
        builtin echo ${1}
    fi
}

logger_check_app_dir(){

    if [ "$logger_LOG_ENABLED" -eq $TRUE ]; then
        dir=$(logger_abs $1)
        if [ ! -d ${dir} ]; then
            #log a seperation line
            mkdir $dir
        fi
    fi
}

# Delete old log files
# $1 Log directory
# $2 Log filename
# $3 Log filename suffix
# $4 Max backup index
logger_delete_old_files(){
    ##### Added for testing
    builtin echo "Running logger_delete_old_files $@" >&2
    #####
    if [ "$logger_LOG_ENABLED" -eq $TRUE ] && [ -n "$3" ] && [ "$4" -gt 0 ]; then
        local directory=$(logger_abs $1)
        local filename=$2
        local maxBackupIndex=$4
        local suffix=$(echo "${3}" | sed -re 's/[^.]/?/g')
        local logFileList=$(find "${directory}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "${filename}${suffix}" -type f | xargs ls -1rt)
        local fileCnt=$(builtin echo -e "${logFileList}" | wc -l)
        local fileToDeleteCnt=$(($fileCnt-$maxBackupIndex))
        local fileToDelete=($(builtin echo -e "${logFileList}" | head -n "${fileToDeleteCnt}" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'))

        ##### Added for testing
        builtin echo "logger_delete_old_files About to start deletion ${fileToDelete[@]}" >&2
        #####

        if [ ${fileToDeleteCnt} -gt 0 ]; then
            for f in "${fileToDelete[@]}"; do
                #### Added for testing
                builtin echo "Removing file ${f}" >&2
                ####
                builtin eval rm -f ${f}
            done
        fi
    fi
}

#Appender
# $1 Log directory
# $2 Log file
# $3 Log file roll ?
# $4 Appender Name
logger_filename(){
    builtin echo "Running logger_filename $@" >&2
    local format
    local filename

    logger_check_app_dir "${1}"

    if [ ${3} -eq 1 ];then
        local formatProp=${4}_roll_format
        format=${!formatProp}
        if [ -z ${format} ]; then
            format=$logger_appender_file_format
        fi
        local suffix=.`date "+${format}"`

        filename=${1}/${2}${suffix}

        # Old log files deletion
        local previousFilenameVar=int_${4}_file_previous
        local maxBackupIndexVar=${4}_maxBackupIndex

        if [ -n "${!maxBackupIndexVar}" ] && [ "${!previousFilenameVar}" != "${filename}" ]; then
            builtin echo "logger_filename Stepped into if: $previousFilenameVar => ${!previousFilenameVar}" >&2
            builtin eval export $previousFilenameVar=$filename
            logger_delete_old_files "${1}" "${2}" "${suffix}" "${!maxBackupIndexVar}"
        fi
    else
        filename=${1}/${2}
    fi

    builtin echo $filename
}

######################## Added for testing
filename_caller(){
    builtin echo "filename_caller Call $1"
    output=$(logger_abs $(logger_filename "${logger_appender_f_dir}" "${logger_appender_f_file}" "1" "logger_appender_f" ))

    builtin echo ${output}
}

#### Previous logs generation
for i in {1101..1120}; do
    file="${logger_appender_f_file}.2012${i:2:3}"
    builtin echo "${file} $i"
    touch -m -t "2012${i}0000" ${logger_appender_f_dir}/$file
done

for i in {1..4}; do
    filename_caller $i
done
```

Here is the output

```
test.log.201201 1101
test.log.201202 1102
test.log.201203 1103
test.log.201204 1104
test.log.201205 1105
test.log.201206 1106
test.log.201207 1107
test.log.201208 1108
test.log.201209 1109
test.log.201210 1110
test.log.201211 1111
test.log.201212 1112
test.log.201213 1113
test.log.201214 1114
test.log.201215 1115
test.log.201216 1116
test.log.201217 1117
test.log.201218 1118
test.log.201219 1119
test.log.201220 1120
filename_caller Call 1
/web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201310
filename_caller Call 2
/web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201310
filename_caller Call 3
/web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201310
filename_caller Call 4
/web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201310
Running logger_filename /web/com/138245668210919 test.log 1 logger_appender_f
logger_filename Stepped into if: int_logger_appender_f_file_previous => 
Running logger_delete_old_files /web/com/138245668210919 test.log .201310 10
logger_delete_old_files About to start deletion /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201201 /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201202 /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201203 /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201204 /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201205 /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201206 /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201207 /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201208 /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201209 /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201210
Removing file /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201201
Removing file /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201202
Removing file /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201203
Removing file /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201204
Removing file /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201205
Removing file /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201206
Removing file /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201207
Removing file /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201208
Removing file /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201209
Removing file /web/com/138245668210919/test.log.201210
Running logger_filename /web/com/138245668210919 test.log 1 logger_appender_f
logger_filename Stepped into if: int_logger_appender_f_file_previous => 
Running logger_delete_old_files /web/com/138245668210919 test.log .201310 10
logger_delete_old_files About to start deletion 
Running logger_filename /web/com/138245668210919 test.log 1 logger_appender_f
logger_filename Stepped into if: int_logger_appender_f_file_previous => 
Running logger_delete_old_files /web/com/138245668210919 test.log .201310 10
logger_delete_old_files About to start deletion 
Running logger_filename /web/com/138245668210919 test.log 1 logger_appender_f
logger_filename Stepped into if: int_logger_appender_f_file_previous => 
Running logger_delete_old_files /web/com/138245668210919 test.log .201310 10
logger_delete_old_files About to start deletion
```

I'd expect logger_filename function to step into the following `if` only when the calculated log filename is different from the previous one:

```
if [ -n "${!maxBackupIndexVar}" ] && [ "${!previousFilenameVar}" != "${filename}" ]; then
```

For this scenario to apply, I'd need ${!previousFilenameVar} to be correctly set, but it's not the case, so logger_filename steps into this `if` all the time which is really not necessary...

It looks like the issue is due to the following line not working properly:

```
builtin eval export $previousFilenameVar=$filename
```

I have a some theories to explain why:

- in the original code, functions are declared and exported as readonly which makes them unable to modify global variable. I removed readonly declarations in the above sample, but probleme persists.
- Function calls are performed in $() which should make them run into seperated shell instances so variable modified are not exported to the main shell

But I cannot manage to find a workaround to this issue...

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you change? Don't make us diff your code against the upstream. Tell us what the input is, what the expected and actual outputs are, and post a self-contained snippet of code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I made a sample and added more details so that the issue is more obvious.

Comment: Your second theory is correct. `log4bash_filename` is executed in a new process, so the change to `previousFilenameVar` is local to that process.

Comment: So there's basicly no workaround to apply?

Comment: Short of writing to a temporary file and reading from that, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply decided to change the way `logger_filename` function is called:

```
#Appender
# $1 Log directory
# $2 Log file
# $3 Log file roll ?
# $4 Appender Name
# $5 Output filename variable
logger_filename(){
#return result
        local format
        local filename

        logger_check_app_dir "${1}"

        if [ ${3} -eq 1 ];then
                local formatProp=${4}_roll_format
                format=${!formatProp}
                if [ -z ${format} ]; then
                        format=$logger_appender_file_format
                fi
                local suffix=.`date "+${format}"`

                filename=${1}/${2}${suffix}

                # Old log files deletion
                local previousFilenameVar=${4}_file_previous
                local maxBackupIndexVar=${4}_maxBackupIndex

                if [ -n "${!maxBackupIndexVar}" ] && [ "${!previousFilenameVar}" != "${filename}" ]; then
                        eval $previousFilenameVar=$filename
                        logger_delete_old_files "${1}" "${2}" "${suffix}" "${!maxBackupIndexVar}"
                fi
        else
                filename=${1}/${2}
        fi

        #builtin echo $filename
        eval $5=$filename
}

local logFileName=
logger_filename "${logFileDir}" "${logFile}" "${logFileRoll}" "${3}" logFileName
builtin echo "$2" >>"$(logger_abs "${logFileName}")"
```

This way the function is not executed in a subshell and variable `${!previousFilenameVar}` is kept in the scope.